# Adding printf to the starting of all functions in a file

Tags: python, c, perl

I have some very large C files, having lots of functions. I need to trace the execution path at run time. There is no way I can trace it through debugging as its a hypervisor code currently running over qemu and doing a lot of binary translations.

Can anyone point me to some script in Perl or Python which can add a `printf` at the starting of all functions and the text could be something like "I am in < function name >"?

Answer (score 24):

Just pass `-finstrument-functions` to gcc when compiling. See the `gcc(1)` man page for details.

Comment: Perfect answer to the spirit of the question.

Comment: +1. Just to add, then entry code might look like:
printf("Function details: %s\n", ____PRETTY_FUNCTION____); ____PRETTY_FUNCTION____ is predefined macro that provides a string containing function name + signature.

Comment: Note: you need to implement each trace function manually, or use a tool like `etrace` that parses the ELF and generates those calls for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176284/why-doesnt-finstrument-functions-work-for-me

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [nice example](http://ndevilla.free.fr/etrace/) of what you want.