# Any tool to log the execution path of a program?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

Is there any tool to log the execution path of functions that a program goes through?
I know gdb can show the backtrace at a particular point. But I want to see the whole story of a program. For instance:

```
int main(){
    a();
    b();
}
void a(){
    c();
}
```

The tool gives out something like:

```
a-----
  c------
b------
```

Comment: Is this a program you created?  Your options will change depending on if you have the source code or not.

Answer (score 2):

[gcc itself can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078680/adding-printf-to-the-starting-of-all-functions-in-a-file/3078693#3078693).

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of how to do it. Because getting the name of a function based on its address (which is basically all you get with `-finstrument-functions`) is not a trivial task.