# Can anyone suggest a way to trace every call of a function?

Tags: c, linux, perl

I want to trace each path of function calls. 
For eg:

```
int a()
{
    b();
    return 1;
}
void b()
{
}
int main()
{
    int x=a();
    return 0;
}
```

So my call trace is main->a->b
In this manner I want to trace each set paths of calls.
I have thought of a depth first search. But i am not sure how this would go.
Can anyone suggest me any concrete method to be implemented in perl?
I will have  C program file and will run a perl script over it to get call traces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding printf to the starting of all functions in a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078680/adding-printf-to-the-starting-of-all-functions-in-a-file)

Comment: but that will involve fiddling with kernel and it will be too much worm if i have to undo some of them or all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of free call-graph programs listed in this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_graph), including [egypt](http://www.gson.org/egypt/) which is a small Perl script that uses gcc and Graphviz to generate the static call graph of a C program.

Comment: these types of tools are typically for static analysis only, and would not work for functions called via a pointer

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can do just that.

Answer (score 0):

One way is automatically instrument the source code with probes that collect the information you want as the program runs.   You can use a program transformation tool to do that.

Here's [a paper on how do collect information abouth "which blocks" get executed](http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf), using a transformation system to insert such probes.  A very small change to the specification of where to put probes, and some minor work to capture the current function would accomplish what you want in a relaible way.